# :nth child not working in jquery

Tags: php, jquery, css-selectors

I am trying to insert a `<br clear="all" />` after each fifth div. Below is how I create the divs in php and then I try to use jquery to seperate them. But it is not working! Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

PHP:

```php
$get = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Products $cate ") or die(mysql_error());
    while($row= mysql_fetch_array($get)){
        $pname = $row['Pname'];
        $image = $row['Pimage'];
        $id = $row['ID'];
        ?>
    <div class="productCat"><a href="product.php?id=<?php echo $id ?>"><img src="../products/<?php echo $image ?>" width="100" height="100" /><br /><?php echo $pname ?></a></div>

        <?php
        }
    ?>
```

JQUERY:

```
$(".productCat :nth-child(5)").append("<br clear='all'/>");
```

Comment: Isn't the clear attribute deprecated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't supposed to be a space after `.productCat`.

Also, why not just do it in the PHP?  Just add a counter:

```
$count=0;
while($row= mysql_fetch_array($get)){
    $count++;
    $pname = $row['Pname'];
    $image = $row['Pimage'];
    $id = $row['ID'];
    ?>
<div class="productCat"><a href="product.php?id=<?php echo $id ?>"><img src="../products/<?php echo $image ?>" width="100" height="100" /><br /><?php echo $pname ?></a></div>

    <?php
    if($count%5==0)
         echo "<br clear='all'/>";
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

put the space out between class selector and nth-child :

```
$(".productCat:nth-child(5)").append("");
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that it's looking for the multiple-of-five-th *children* of `.productCat`, because of the extra space. EDIT: Actually, it's only looking for the 5th child of `.productCat`, because you left the `n` out.

Besides, what's wrong with:

```css
/* CSS: */
.productCat:nth-child(5n+1) {clear: left;}
```

This CSS-only solution is far more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Why not doing it in PHP ? If you use jQuery, people without javascript won't have your "br" ...

```
<?php
$get = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM Products '.$cate) or die(mysql_error());
$i=0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($get)){
    $i++:
    ?>
    <div class="productCat"><a href="product.php?id=<?php echo $row['ID']; ?>"><img src="../products/<?php echo $row['Pimage']; ?>" width="100" height="100" /><br /><?php echo $row['Pname']; ?></a></div>
    <?php
    if($i == 5){
        echo '<br clear="all" />';
        $i=0;
    }
}
?>
```